# phpQuery find id

Tags: php, phpquery

I'm using phpQuery to parse a site:

HTML example:

```
<div class="post" id="1232323">
   <div class="title">Example</div>
   <div class="text">texttexttext</div>
</div>
```

I can find the title and text but can't find id from div.post.

```
$document = phpQuery::newDocument(takeCode("example.com"));
$list_elements = $document->find('div.Post');
foreach ($list_elements as $element) 
{
   $pq = pq($element);
   $postTitle = $pq->find('div.Post')->attr('id'); //not found
   $postTitle = $pq->find('div.title')->text(); //found
   $postTitle = $pq->find('div.content')->text(); //found

}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Does `$pq->attr('id')` not give you that id?

Comment: thanks. 

$pq->attr('id')

Comment: Shall I turn this into an answer if it works for you?

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($list_elements as $element) 
{
   $pq = pq($element);
   $postTitle = $pq->attr('id') //!
   $postTitle = $pq->find('div.title')->text(); //found
   $postTitle = $pq->find('div.content')->text(); //found

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the ID, use:

```
 $pq->attr('id');
```